# Probabilistic Modelling of uncertain positions of objects in a 2D-Grid

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have a 2D-Grid which is populated by obstacles of different sizes. A size is always a whole number of cells. An obstacle is at least one cell big.

If I did kown the size of the object but had only an uncertain guess of its position, how can I formulate this in terms of probability theory?

**My attempt:** 
Let us consider the position of one part (always of the size of one cell) of an obstacle as a discrete random variable. It follows that the amount of random variables needed to describe the possible positions of the obstacle is equal to its size. The posititon of an obstacle of size 1 would be fully described by a single random variable.

As a random variable is a function 
$$X: \Omega \rightarrow R$$
$$\omega \mapsto X(\omega)$$

we need to encode the coordinates of the grid $\omega$ as a real number. This can happen according to Matthew Szudzik's elegant pairing function ([see here](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf)). Since a single cell in the grid can not be occupied by several obstacle parts (either of the same obstacle or others), any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
$$P(X = x_i \cap Y=y_i : x_i = y_i) = 0$$

It follows that the probability of a cell being occupied by either of the two obstacle parts is simply the sum of the probabilities of it being occupied by either obstacle:$$P(X=x_i \cup Y=y_i : x_i = y_i) = P(X = x_i) + P(Y = y_i) $$

I'm feeling rather unsure about this forumlation, is it correct? And if not, how can I state the problem correctly in terms of occupancy probability of single cell?

Comment: when you say $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent where do the $X,Y$ come from in the next display?

Comment: That's just a typo, I meant to write $X,Y$ instead of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Corrected it

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent and $P(X=x_i)>0$ $P(Y=x_i)>0$ then $P(X=x_i, \cup Y = x_i) >0$.  So I think $X,Y$ are not independent.